# Background image will not fit in the whole page in App.css in create-react-app

Tags: css, create-react-app

I'm not sure why but any image I choose for the page's background is never 100% entirely shown. I'm not sure if create-react-app has something to do with it or what but there is always some part of the image that is overflowing and gets cut from the page.

```
body{
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516849677043-ef67c9557e16?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I need the image to be shown in its entirety. background-size: 100% doesn't seem to do it inside create-react-app for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried background-size: contain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, background-size: 100% will fill the screen with the image, and crop it if necessary.

I think what you want is to see the whole image. You should use contain for that:

```css
    html {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: red url('http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/groningen-city-view- picture-id588880579?s=612x612') no-repeat center;
     background-size:contain;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/u6hgLowk/)

Comment: Okay thanks, this worked! The image is now fully contained in the page but it is not fully covering the page and I can see why. My only question now is what kind of image would work to cover the whole page AND be 100% shown on the page? Does it depend on the dimensions??

Comment: It's impossible to know the dimensions of the end-users' screen. Your best bet is to have a background color which is more forgiving behind the image. (Change red to black for example in my snippet)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
body {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516849677043-ef67c9557e16?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `width: 100%` gives horizontal scroll to the page.

Comment: Not with overflow hidden.

Comment: Why to complicate things, without width it will work.

Comment: Do you mean, "Why would you complicate things?". 
This is a hack for early browsers. This method's coverage is wider.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done purly with `CSS`, look for some basic `CSS` [background](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) properties

```
body{
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516849677043-ef67c9557e16?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
    background-size: cover;             //contains these values - auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;       //contains these values - repeat|repeat-x|repeat-y|no-repeat|initial|inherit;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;       //contains these values - scroll|fixed|local|initial|inherit; 
}
```

**Note:** Look for `background-attachment` property, if you don't need it you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work with this:

```
.background-image {
  background-image: url('XXX');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Similar to above answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).